# Create a file in RoR, then send its URL in a JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making an API which generate files and send links to them for later download.

What I have right now is

- The file generated in public/XXX
- The absolute path to this file.

Is it the correct place to put this kind of generated files ?

How to generate an URL for this file in my controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like carrierwave for this.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

In this you create an uploader, mount it on a column on your model and the use column_url to get the file name.

Comment: The file is generated - no upload takes place.
I also don't have any model (yet even a database)

Comment: Upload is just a generic word, it is really just saving, I don't know your specific situation or domain, but would recommend creating a class to manage this and then just save them using the mounted uploader.  Then you will be able to just use all the stuff carrierwave has already written.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is a download action in my controller.

```
  def download
    send_file "#{Rails.public_path}/#{params[:path]}.#{params[:format]}"
  end
```

With an appropriate route in my routes files:

```
  get '/controller/download/:path' => 'controller#download'
```

And to generate the URL:

```
url_for(:controller => : controller, :action => :download, :path => "a_path")
```